# CSS what value does Canvas Skew use in setTransform?

Tags: css, canvas, skew

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_settransform.asp

context.setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f);

W3C schools says `"Skew the the drawings horizontally"`, but which value does it use?

It seems it's not degrees like the CSS skews things, and neither does it use PI. Explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transformation matrix—a set of nine numbers that are used to transform a two-dimensional array, such as a bitmap, using linear algebra. the last set of the matrix is always 0 0 1 so it takes six different parameters

Please have a look at this

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/MatrixTransforms/MatrixTransforms.html

Answer (score 3):

In your example transform, the b & c would respectively represent the horizontal and vertical skew.

The transform matrix is arranged like this:

```
context.setTransform(scaleX, skewX, skewY, scaleY, translateX, translateY);
```

The amount of skew is a tangent angle that's expressed in radians.

So this will skew 30 degrees horizontally:

```
    var tan30degrees=Math.tan( 30*Math.PI/180 );

    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(1,tan30degrees,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.fillRect(100,100,50,50);
    ctx.restore();
```

[image]